# Serial console to Pi 4b shows no output

Tags: raspbian, hardware, serial-console

I am trying to connect to the Pi 4b 8Gb via serial console, however, although I can connect to the serial adapter itself, I can't seem to get no output at all from it, nor using default raspbian settings, nor from the cmdline.txt settings below. Since I am currently deploying a PXE environment which is failing to boot, it is really frustrating not to be able to use the serial console. Am I missing something? Thanks

**What I tried so far**

1. Connecting without GND
2. Swapping TXD with RXD
3. Tried different FT232R serial adapter (they both work fine)
4. Tried from default raspbian settins on sdcard and PXE

**Command I use to connect to the serial**

```
sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

**cmdline.txt**

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=172.12.1.1:/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0,vers=3 rw ip=dhcp rootwait elevator=deadline
```

**Serial pinout**

6 GND
8 TXD
10 RXD

[image: Serial adapater]

Comment: in the picture you have RX connected to RX and TX to TX ... so, swap that for a start

Comment: as I mentioned in my post, I already tried that with no luck.

Comment: what happens if you use `console=serial1,115200` instead?

Comment: Check for activity with [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) or [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py)

Comment: @JaromandaX makes no difference I am afraid.

Comment: To see if the pins work ("1. Connecting without GND" is potentially damaging), disable the serial console and try a manual exchange with the UART or just set them as normal GPIO outputs and check if they are properly controllable -- or just connect the TX and RX together on the pi and do a manual test.

Comment: I managed to get it working by enabling uart boot and swapping TX with RX and a lot of patience. Thanks everyone.